# Why can't the input numbers be displayed in console log even after a for loop for the function triggered by the number input addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 `input` fields for numbers, and I'd like to fire in the console log, every time I input a number in any of the 3 `input` fields. I've added a for loop for the `addEventListener`, but there's still the error showing that this `addEventListener` part is not a function. I'd like to ask what am I missing for the code to be realized?

Thank you so much!

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="no1">
<input type="number" id="no2">
<input type="number" id="no3">
```

JS:

```
const val = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    val[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
        console.log(val[i].value);
    });
}
```

Comment: @j08691 Sorry for the spelling, but it's still not working.

Comment: Change the for loop to: `for (let i = 0; ...` which will scope `i` to the body of the for loop. The problem is that you defined `i` globally. After the for loop finishes `i` points to `3` and that index is obviously `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Typo, missing the plural s in elementsByTagName

Also `console.log(val[i].value);` is not known inside the eventListener you use.

to fix that, you could do

```
val[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
    console.log(this.value); // "this" is available because we use function 
});
```

or

```
val[i].addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value); // "this" is NOT available in an arrow function
});
```

Here is a more elegant method using delegation

Note the DOMContentLoaded - that is triggered when the page has loaded all HTML

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("numberContainer").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches("[type=number]")) return; // or some other test for example class
    console.log(tgt.id,tgt.value)
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="numberContainer">
<input type="number" id="no1">
<input type="number" id="no2">
<input type="number" id="no3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that within your event handler, the `val` array is not defined.  You should read up on closures to learn why this is the case.

To solve your particular issue, you can make the following changes - your event handler should accept an `event` argument, which includes, among other things, a currentTarget attribute, which in this case will be the `<input>` element that fired the event.

```js
const val = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
   val[i].addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
});
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="no1">
<input type="number" id="no2">
<input type="number" id="no3">
```